# set Caps Lock to shift (all keys)

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, capslock

Under `Keyboard Layout > Options > Caps Lock key behaviour` one of the options is:

- Caps Lock toggles shift so all keys are affected.

I have that one selected (see screenshot), but when I do <kbd>caps lock</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>caps lock</kbd>, I still get `5` (not `%`).

[image: caps lock key behaviour Ubuntu]

Am I misunderstanding what this option is supposed to mean?

Comment: That is the normal Caps Lock behavior, you want something like "shift lock".

Answer (score 1):

You want to make Caps Lock work like Shift, so you can set the behavior to the third one.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: You can use the option "Caps Lock works like Shift with locking. Shift "pauses" Caps Lock."

Comment: @alb3rtano0012: if a user doesn't understand your answer, make a screen shot, [edit] your answer, upload it and make it more clear or provide a command that will solve it for them.  (you've got enough reputation to do this)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, but this was fine. I just didn't understand alb3rtano's wording.

Comment: Uh never mind … this appeared to work, but then five minutes later it doesn't work. `ASDF1234` but the same (third) option is highlighted as it was when it gave the expected output five minutes ago. No idea what determines whether Ubuntu follows the instruction in the keyboard layout or not…